# Insert images/sticker/gif in Edittext in android from custom keyboard/google keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I tried to insert emoji using keyboard like Google keyboard `Gboard` to my `edittext` but it shows toast `This text field does not support GIF insertion from the keyboard`.

[image]

There are couple of question regarding the same but don't have proper answer,. I read the [documentation reference given](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard#how_it_works), but not given the implementation.I tried this but it is not triggering `onCommitContent` -

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this) {
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
        final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);

        final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback =
            new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                        int flags, Bundle opts) {
                    // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                    if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                        InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                        try {
                            inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            return false; // return false if failed
                        }
                    }

                    // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
                    // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.

                    return true;  // return true if succeeded
                }
            };
        return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback);
    }
};
```

but apps like Whatsapp, Telegram supports this feature. Do i need to create custom EditText or something ?

Comment: I think you are missing `setmimetype` .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As given in your question it looks like you don't have set content mime type. I have created a `EditText` with callback `keyBoardInputCallbackListener` which detect if any `gif/png/jpg/webp` is inserted via softkeyboard.

```
public class MyEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

  private String[] imgTypeString;
  private KeyBoardInputCallbackListener keyBoardInputCallbackListener;

  public MyEditText(Context context) {
      super(context);
      initView();
  }

  public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      initView();
  }

  private void initView() {
      imgTypeString = new String[]{"image/png",
            "image/gif",
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/webp"};
  }

  @Override
  public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
      final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
      EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(outAttrs,
              imgTypeString);
      return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, outAttrs, callback);
  }


  final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback =
        new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                                           int flags, Bundle opts) {

                // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                        InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                    try {
                        inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return false; // return false if failed
                    }
                }
                boolean supported = false;
                for (final String mimeType : imgTypeString) {
                    if (inputContentInfo.getDescription().hasMimeType(mimeType)) {
                        supported = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!supported) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (keyBoardInputCallbackListener != null) {
                    keyBoardInputCallbackListener.onCommitContent(inputContentInfo, flags, opts);
                }
                return true;  // return true if succeeded
            }
        };

  public interface KeyBoardInputCallbackListener {
      void onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                         int flags, Bundle opts);
  }

  public void setKeyBoardInputCallbackListener(KeyBoardInputCallbackListener keyBoardInputCallbackListener) {
      this.keyBoardInputCallbackListener = keyBoardInputCallbackListener;
  }

  public String[] getImgTypeString() {
      return imgTypeString;
  }

  public void setImgTypeString(String[] imgTypeString) {
      this.imgTypeString = imgTypeString;
  }
}
```

Use this in your activity class -

```
MyEditText myEditText = (MyEditText)findViewbyId(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.setKeyBoardInputCallbackListener(new KeyBoardInputCallbackListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                             int flags, Bundle opts) {
                        //you will get your gif/png/jpg here in inputContentInfo 
                       // You can use a webView or ImageView to load the gif

                            Uri linkUri = inputContentInfo.getLinkUri();
                            mWebView.loadUrl(linkUri != null ? linkUri.toString() : "null");

                    }
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks karan.. Maybe you could add the part on how to handle the gif link after that..

Comment: i used this code in my application. It working fine, but getting one problem in bundle i am receiving null value. Can you please help me sort this out.

Comment: did the same as above, but not able to override onCommitContent() in my current activity

Comment: I get bundle is `null`