# Flutter: Enable GIF insertion on TextField

Tags: android, flutter, gif

I can't find a way to enable GIFs insertion on the TextFields.

When I open for example Gboard and select a GIF or Sticker it says `appXX doesn't support gif insertion here`

Do anyone have a solution for this please? I read [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184426/2335912) but it's on native Android (Java). I did not found any flutter package on pub.dev too

Comment: it's not possible within current flutter. I've just spent 10 hours trying to find out how to do this or create my own plugin but there's no viable solution anywhere. The only options that exist is using a button external to the keyboard to hold the values of the gif or sticker and then processing that image with image.network or equivalent. Very painful for me and very pathetic of flutter.

Comment: if there's any updates on this situation, I'd really appreciate if you post an update here :))